# what is the main difference between Yogachara and Madhyamaka?

Tags: mahayana

According to Wikipedia, there are two main schools in Mahayana, [Yogachara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogachara) and [Madhyamaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhyamaka).

Could you tell me the main difference in doctrine between these two?

Comment: Can you please give us some kind of context for this question? Why are you comparing the two, what are you looking for that can't be found in Wikipedia etc